# Python unittest main method interfering with main method of my script

Tags: python, unit-testing, scripting, program-entry-point

I have a script with a main method (`if __name__ == '__main__':`, etc), and I am trying to test using unittest, and [the basic example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html), suggests putting `unittest_main()` in your main method. It seems to be overriding anything that I was previously doing in my `main` method. For example, any arguments that the script used to take are now being funneled to unittest. Any tips here?

Comment: Don't unit-test scripts; unit-test modules. Your script is just an interface between an external resource and your modules.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson @chepner ! I can now confirm that what I am working on is a module as it is importable and reusable. Would you change your previous answer about creating a wrapper given this information?

Answer (score 1):

Make your script a thin wrapper around a module:

```
import mymodule

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mymodule.main()
```

The script now doesn't need unit-testing (or rather, all it needs is to mock `mymodule` and confirm that it calls `mymodule.main()`), and all your testable logic is in a module that cannot be run as a script.